# How to do a join on two entities in Symfony and Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, inner-join

I have a select query and I'm trying to add a join to it.

In the example below, I have a `Question`entity that I use to return some results, and I want to add a join with the `User` entity, like:

`SELECT question  FROM question AS q LEFT JOIN USER u ON q.user_id= u.id;`

I would like the result to be a `User` entity inside a `Question` entity, something like:

```
private Question (entity)
private id
private user_id
private User (entity)
    private id
    private name
```

here is my class

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Question;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

class QuestionRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * @param int $currentPage
     *
     * @return Paginator
     */
    public function getQuestions($currentPage = 1)
    {
        $questions = $this->createQueryBuilder('question')
            ->where('question.active is NULL')
            ->getQuery();

        $paginator = $this->paginate($questions, $currentPage);

        return $paginator;
    }
}
```

I call it like this

```
$questionRepo = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Question');
$questions    = $questionRepo->getQuestions(1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
$questions = $this->createQueryBuilder('question')
    ->leftJoin('question.user', 'question_user', 'WITH', 'question_user.user = :user_id')
    ->where('question.active is NULL')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
    ->getQuery();

$paginator = $this->paginate($questions, $currentPage);
```

---

Edit: Because of your latest comments, i have to mention, that this suggestion is assuming that your `Question` entity looks like this (according `User`'s entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="question")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

If not, add this, generate entities (`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Question`) and update DB (`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`).

PS: Before generating entities, you'll have to remove old getters/setters.

Comment: I get `[Semantical Error] near 'question_user': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Question has no association named user`

Comment: I think I need to tell the `Question` entity that I have a `User` entity